# javascript object firefox watch

Tags: javascript, object, firefox

I've encountered a very strange thing in Firefox javascript. I've got an Object I've created and I'm using strings as the keys. When I hit the point where I'm seeing if I've got value for the key 'watch' it reacts by returning me the Object.watch function if there isn't a key for 'watch' in there. I'm trying to access the key/value with:

```
my_object["watch"]
```

I can get around this by initializing that value on creation of the Object but that seems mega-cheesy to me. Is there a way to work around this that is programmatically. I can write:

```
Object.keys(my_object).indexOf("watch")
```

to make a decision if the key is actually there but that's really expensive. My script in Chrome from around 5-10 seconds to a minute or more.

I just can't believe that there's not a performant way in firefox to deal with this issue. Chrome does the "right thing"

Comment: What about `my_object.hasOwnProperty("watch")`?

Comment: smokin' fast. perfect, though I'm really disappointed that we have to jump through hoops in firefox only. Make this an answer and I'll vote it up and accept. thanks!

Comment: No problem! @Felix already has provided the same answer - I'd just take his.

Answer (score 2):

It does **not** return `Object.watch`. [`Object.prototype.watch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/watch) is a Firefox specific function.

You can use `obj.hasOwnProperty('watch')` to test whether your object has that property or not.

Alternatively, depending on how the object is used and where it comes from, you could initialize it without a prototype:

```
var obj = Object.create(null);
```

Then your existing test (`obj['watch']`) will work just fine.